# How to clear Session used in paging of a gridview

Tags: asp.net, session, gridview, paging

I have implemented paging in Gridview and in order to avoid frequent Reconnection with database,I used Session to store data.So that data could be retrieved from session on changing page index of Gridview.
But my problem is that when should I clear this session as it's usable only for this very page.And if I use ViewState then it will not be fine if data increases in amount.

Looking forward for valuable suggestion of yours.....
Thanks in advance
Supriya

Comment: Better way is just retrieve rows for each page. But it need to fetch data for each page click. If data is big, loading all data and keep in session will cause performance issue and may result out of memory exception.

Comment: you better use Cache instead of session/viewstate ... so that we can keep some expire time so that will be done automatically.. if its common for all users ...

Answer (score 0):

You should not be saving any data to sessions. If the data control requires data per page it is fine to select only the rows you need from the data base per page change.

So if you have say 100 rows and 10 rows per page, then you should be retrieving 10 rows per PageChange of the data control. This is perfectly acceptable especially when combined with caching.

Ifyou are using SQl 2005 see this post:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/07/434787.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should worry about the database connections. Connection pooling will take case of that. You have to open connection and close as soon as you get paged records.

If you store your records in viewstate/cache this will unnecesarily use resources and might be out of sync with database. I consider it as a bad approach.

You should make a call each time you change page and retrieve records from db.

Hope it helps.